# Is applying the Poynting Vector to a DC circuit incorrect?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, poynting-vector

The Poynting vector can be defined as:
the Poynting vector magnitude is the rate of energy flux in watts per square meter and whose direction is the direction of propagation of the electromagnetic radiation.

-In a DC circuit the electric field used for the Poynting vector are surface charges on the wires and the magnetic field is from current electrons in the wire.  While the electric field of the surface charges and the magnetic field from the current electrons are perpendicular, the fields have no originating coupling as in alternating current.

-In AC, current electrons produce both the electric field and magnetic field which results in electromagnetic radiation.

-In DC, the magnetic field is passing through the surface charges.  This relationship does not produce electromagnetic radiation.

If the Poynting vector is referring to electromagnetic radiation then how can the vector be used in a DC circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The Poyting vector $\vec{S}=\vec{E}\times\vec{H}$ and Poynting's theorem require no radiation or even time-varying fields to be present: they are perfectly valid for a DC circuit. For example, integrating the Poynting vector across a closed surface $S$ surrounding a resistor will yield the power dissipated in this resistor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I can better understand that the integrating the Poynting vector across a closed surface can yield information about the power being dissipated in the resistor.  But, without electromagnetic radiation there cannot be any meaningful transfer of energy from one location to another.  The fields can be used to indicate what is happening locally in the circuit, but energy delivery along the outside of the wire from the voltage source to resistor does not seem possible with a static fields.

Comment: This is not true. Of course you can have energy transfer without radiation. A resistor connected to battery is just such an example: energy is delivered from the battery to the resistor, with no radiation.

Comment: I agree, but the delivery energy seems only possible through the wires.  The Poynting vector states that energy is delivered outside the wire.  But, your answer does help me understand that the Poynting vector can give information on what is happening locally outside and near the resistor.  The charge build up on the ends of the resistor by partially blocking the current and the increased local electric field through the resistor cause changes in the local external electric field and cause a change in the local Poynting vector.  But, energy delivery outside the wire does not seem possible.

Comment: @MarkJanus1 I am not sure why you think that energy delivery outside the wire is not possible. Such a claim is not consistent with Maxwell’s equations.

Comment: Thank you for follow up. Going to edit the question to better reflect what I think the Poynting vector represents.

Comment: I have an additional question on the Poynting vector.  Going to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The Poynting vector describes the flow of electromagnetic energy through the fields, not radiation. While radiation does carry energy, so do static fields. A battery provides energy which moves through the static fields, as described by Poynting’s theorem, to be finally deposited in the load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I agree that static fields can delivery energy, but not over a distance and wires can be very long.  The static fields are local and radiate outward.  The Poynting vector seems only to be an arrow pointing perpendicular to two static fields which are perpendicular to each other.  What is the method of energy delivery along the outside of the wire if the fields remain static and point away from the wires?

Comment: You are incorrect about the geometry of the field lines. The electric field is radial but the magnetic field is circular. The energy flows perpendicular to both, which is in the direction parallel to the wire. The energy transfer is exactly as it should be by Poynting’s theorem.

Comment: Thank you for follow up.  Point away from the wires is a poor description.  I have seen diagrams of the Poynting vector and observed how the vector can point in a direction.  Perhaps a better statement is: fields remain static and radiate away from the wires.  The deliver of energy over a distance does not seem possible with static fields, yet that is the claim of the Poynting  vector.

Comment: Yes, that is the claim of the Poynting vector and it is consistent with observations. The energy doesn’t go far away from the wire, but it can travel quite long distances along the wire.

Comment: Thank you for follow up.  Going to edit the question to better reflect what I think the Poynting vector represents.

Comment: I have an additional question on the Poynting vector. Going to ask a new question.